# Storing SQL output as python variables and storing in text files

Tags: python, sql

I'm pretty much new to python and SQL and I am trying some coding tasks. I have a SQL query in the format of the below, where I return a set of values using python and SQL. What I would like to do using python is to define the variable "X as User_Name" and parse this to a text file within my local linux directory (for example in a file called Usernames.txt).

```
query = """\
Select 
    X as User_Name,
    Y,
    Z
FROM
    tbl1
WHERE ...
AND ... """
```

In the below snippets I attempt to write this to the text file, but does not seem to work for me

```
cursor = connection.cursor()
....
fo = open ('/localDrive/Usernames.txt', 'a')
for row in cur:
   rows = list(row)
   fo.write(rows[0])
....

fo.close()
```

The issue is sometimes there are more than 1 row returned so I'd need to store all usernames in that text file. I'd like then to be able to check against this text file and not return SQL Output if the "X as User_Name" already exists within the text file (Usernames.txt) This is something I'm not sure how to do

Comment: Edited now, was a typo

Comment: Open the file before the for-loop, write to it in the loop and close after the loop. You may have to add a newline character when writing to have the names on different lines.

Comment: Does it have to be a .txt file? A good way to store your database output would be to use pickle
https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html

edit: added link to tutorial about how to use it:
https://www.datacamp.com/tutorial/pickle-python-tutorial

Comment: If the file doesn't exist at the time your SQL query runs, then you should look at doing the 'de-duplication' in the SQL statement itself.

Answer (score 0):

Just use [Pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) to save your data, with [dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) and [sets](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets) to compare them.  Pickle can save and load Python objects with no parsing required.

If you want a human readable output as well, just print the objects to the screen or file.

e.g. (untested)

```
import pickle
from pathlib import Path

pickle_path = Path("data.pickle")

fields = ('field_1', 'field_2', 'field_3')

def add_fields(data_list):
    # Return a list of dictionaries
    return [dict(zip(fields, row)) for row in data_list]

def get_unique_values(dict_list, key):
    # Return a set of key field values
    return set(dl[key] for dl in dict_list)

def get_data_subset(dict_list, key_field, keys):
    # Return records where key_field contains values in keys
    return [dl for dl in dict_list if dl[key_field] in keys]

# ...
# Create DB connection etc.
# ...
# ...
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute(query)
results = cursor.fetchall()

# De-serialise the local data if it exists
if pickle_path.exists():
    with pickle_path.open("rb") as pp:
        prev_results = pickle.load(pp)
else:
    prev_results = []

results = add_fields(results)

keys = get_unique_values(results, 'field_1')

prev_keys = get_unique_values(prev_results, 'field_1')

# All keys
all_keys = keys | prev_keys

# in both sets
existing_keys = keys ^ prev_keys

# just in prev
deleted_keys = prev_keys - keys

# just the new values in keys
new_keys = keys - prev_keys

# example: handle deleted data
temp_dl = []
for row in prev_results:
    if row['field_1'] not in deleted_keys:
        temp_dl.append(row)
prev_results = temp_dl

# example: handle new keys
new_data = get_data_subset(results, 'field_1', new_keys)
prev_results.extend(new_data)

# Serialise the local data
if pickle_path.exists():
    pickle_path.unlink()
with pickle_path.open("wb") as pp:
    pickle.dump(prev_results, pp)

if len(new_data):
    print("New records added")
    for row in new_data:
        print(row)
```